# In token based authentication, is the token provided on every request?

Tags: authentication, token

I have created a token based authentication system for my iOS and android app. I am trying to figure out if I should provide the token on every request or does some sort of session or cookie get stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually yes the token is passed in every request.. In addition to that apps may use cookies etc...to manage sessions as well..  OAuth should give you some sense of how this works at a high level...
I have found studying api of flicker and amazon useful as well..
An application that I have worked on uses this mechanism and stores some additional info using cookies (I think it used web views..). The session can be stored in your back-end.